# How can I read this dataset from its url?

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

i want to write a program that gives me the options of reading a particular dataset from my local machine or reading it directly from its url source (https://data.world/missdataviz/superstore-2021/workspace/file?filename=Sample+-+Superstore.xls), but i got the error: `ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.`

```
import streamlit as st
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import requests
import os
from io import BytesIO
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

# file upload
fl = st.file_uploader(":file_folder: Upload a file", type=(["csv","txt","xlsx","xls"]))
if fl is not None:
    filename = fl.name
    st.write(filename)
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
else:
    # URL of the online data source
    url = "https://data.world/missdataviz/superstore-2021/workspace/file?filename=Sample+-+Superstore.xls"
    response = requests.get(url)
    source_data = response.content
    df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(source_data))
```

I tried different suggestions, particularly with chatgpt, with no success.

Comment: It looks like that url is a plain html page, not the actual xls file.

Answer (score 0):

Load files from remote URLs using `Unstructured`.

```
from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredURLLoader

# arg urls is a list of strings
def load_urls(urls):
    loaders=UnstructuredURLLoader(urls=urls)
    data=loaders.load()
    return data
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your suggestion and got a 'TypeError: 'numpy._DTypeMeta' object is not subscriptable'

Answer (score 0):

In a browser go to your link ( https://data.world/missdataviz/superstore-2021/workspace/file?filename=Sample+-+Superstore.xls ).  Data.world has a download dropdown on the top right corner of the page.  From the dropdown select "Share URL" and you will see how to import that in python.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('https://query.data.world/s/taxp3dmggewmlmi6c7oz6jhzswj7m2?dws=00000')
```

Comment: Thank you. I am now getting a 'KeyError: 'order_date'' after I added the line: 
'df["order_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["order_date"])'
I understand the error is because there isn't an 'order_date' column but I can confirm that there is an 'order_date' column.

Comment: So I answered your first question but I still see no points for helping you.

Comment: Apologies. I’m still learning how to use this platform. I tried ‘upvoting’ by clicking the up arrow but I’m being told I’ll need 15 reputation to use the feature. I really appreciate the help. Thank you

Comment: Some things I would check are is there spaces on either side of the column name e.g. " order_date "